# Checkboxlist with textbox displayed in dropdownlist

Tags: html

I have this requirement that I need a dropdown list that allows multiple selection as well as a textbox to enter quantity for each check. In a way it's checkboxlist with a textbox next to each checkbox. The textbox is disabled until the checkbox next to it is checked.

I can create that just fine. But the problem is when there are many items and list is too long. So I need the checkboxlist to be displayed in a dropdown list style.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Code will be better as I am new to this.

This is the exact functionality I need.

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg3ld.gif

Comment: You definitely need to use JavaScript for this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using javascript. It's not possible using plain HTML.

You can set a max count, and if the number of items exceeds that count, you can use javascript to convert the list into a dropdown.

Ref: Find the reference code [here](https://codepen.io/randhawa/pen/PjvEmg).

**HTML**

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li data-value="value 1">Your list item 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Your list item 2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Your list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
body{
  padding:30px;
}
ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }
```

**JS**

```js
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.
but this just selects the value from the list.

The actual functionality I need is given in the gif file above. pls find the link 
and help me with this